# Why one compartment in an osmotic container have different pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, osmosis

I am reading about osmotic pressure and the derivation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_pressure), states:

> Consider the system at the point when it has reached equilibrium. The condition for this is that the chemical potential of the solvent (since only it is free to flow toward equilibrium) on both sides of the membrane is equal. The compartment containing the pure solvent has a chemical potential of $\mu ^{0}(p)$, where $p$ is the pressure. On the other side, in the compartment containing the solute, the chemical potential of the solvent depends on the mole fraction of the solvent, $0<x_{v}<1$. Besides, this compartment can assume a different pressure, $p'$.

I can't understand why the other compartment can have a different pressure. Isn't pressure in the same height of a fluid the same everywhere? Also both compartments, if we consider the container as a U-shaped tube, are in contact with atmosphere. Isn't therefore the pressure the same in both compartments?

Comment: The pressure might be different because the fluid is different, or because its height is different on both sides, or because of some dude with a pump.

Comment: Take a look at the diagram at the upper right of the Wikipedia article you cite.  Look at the U-shaped tube on the right. The pressure (p) on the RHS of the membrane (at the bottom of the tube) is lower than that on the LHS. That's because the presence of solute on the LHS lowers the chemical potential of the solvent, causing solvent to move from L to R until the increase in chemical potential from the increased p just balances the decreased chemical potential from the presence of the solute. The p difference needed to equalize the solvent's chemical potential on the LHS&RHS is the osmotic p.